# LDAP - Archive Directory

Tags: java, spring, active-directory, ldap

[image: flow]

If you see my picture, I have flow like this:

I want `login` into " Web Application Dashboard ", using existing `username` in the database server (in this case using sql server)

I using Java Spring Framework, I have searched for many tutorials that say we must use `LDAP` `Active Directory`, but I can't understand it.

Comment: Where is your user data stored?

Comment: The best approach is to create yourself a log in module.
http://www.avajava.com/tutorials/lessons/how-do-i-create-a-login-module.html

Answer (score 0):

Light weight directory protocal(ldap) server is popularly used for authentication.It stores the values in form of tree structure.Which is easy to retreive the login credintials when multiple requests come at a time instead of using database.

Popular ldap servers in market are
1.openldap
2.ApacheDirectoryStudio

Use any of these above servers and workout below examples

refer this link for example

1.[springldap Ex 1](http://javabeginnerstutorial.com/tag/ldap-authentication/)

2.[springldap Ex2](http://krams915.blogspot.in/2011/01/spring-security-mvc-using-ldap.html)